# How to determine the optimal number of trees in Random Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees

Here I list possible answers for mine:

1. Do you use the graph for OOB?
2. Do you use any other kind of graph?
3. Do you take a fixed number in default?
4. Do you take in consideration any research paper which explain why you should use x-number of trees?
5. Do you use any piece of code in any package in R or python which you trust to do it for you?

Can you choose which is your solution and give arguments why?

Comment: What do you mean by "graph" in 1/2?

Comment: @JonNordby I mean a graph which in x it has the number of trees and in y it has the OOB error. But someone may use other variables, and Im curious to know.